# Pandas sum and totals using loc or iloc selections on multindex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to update this table 1 (Level I, Level II, and Level III) by using pandas iloc or loc with the dataset referenced below. I am open to a better way than loc and iloc if there are suggestions.

*Table 1*

[image]

***Example 1***

If I want the table to update with new information for the 1102 selection for Pay Grade 13 and Level III I would use the following pd.loc code:

```
jobseries = '1102'
result = df.loc[('3',jobseries),'13']
print (result)
14.0
```

***Example 2:***  This works too.

```
jobseries = '1102'
result = df.loc[('3',jobseries),'13'].sum()
print (result)
14
```

However, the challenge is when I need to select multiple indexes or multiple columns.

**MULTIPLE ROWS**

Now, if I want to update Table 1, Total for all Level I, instead of doing some type of df.isin, I need o do the following:

Example 3:

```
total = df.loc[('1',jobseries),'07'] + df.loc[('1',jobseries),'09'] + and so on...
print (total)
32
```

This works but I believe eventually will throw a RuntimeWarning:  invalid value encountered in long_scalars.  So its not the best way to do this. Any recommendations?

**MULTIPLE COLUMNs**

Now, if I want to update Table 1, # certs for Level I, Level II, and Level III, and any given grade level, I can't figure out the code.  I've tried the following but its throwing a keyError.  I've tried multiple ways of doing this and still cannot figure it out:

***Example 4:***

```
jobseries = '1102'
result = df.loc[('1','2','3',jobseries),'All']
print (result)
KeyError: "None of [[('1', '2', '3', '1102')]] are in the [index]"
```

This is strange because if I check my index the keyError confuses me.

```
df.index:

MultiIndex(levels=[['1', '2', '3', 'All'], ['', '0301', '0341', '0342', '0343', '0501', '0560', '0810', '0850', '1101', '1102', '1105', '1106', '1109', '1145', '1146', '1170', '1410']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 0]],
           names=['Level', 'JobSeries'])
```

I've also tried df.xs:

***Example 5:***

```
jobseries = '1102'
result = df.xs(jobseries, level=1)
print (result)

        01   07   08   09   11    12    13   14   15  All
Level                                                    
1      1.0  0.0  0.0  9.0  8.0   9.0   6.0  0.0  0.0   15
2      0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  6.0  12.0   6.0  1.0  0.0   13
3      1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  11.0  14.0  9.0  3.0   14
```

**CHANGES IN ROWS OR COLUMNS**

The other challenge is that if the dataset changes and index or rows change the pd.loc and pd.iloc will throw a key error.  Is there anyway around this?

df:

```
                 01   07   08    09    11    12    13   14   15  All
Level JobSeries                                                      
1     0341       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      0342       0.0  0.0  1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      0343       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    2
      0560       0.0  0.0  0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      0810       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1101       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1102       1.0  0.0  0.0   9.0   8.0   9.0   6.0  0.0  0.0   15
      1105       0.0  7.0  3.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    9
      1106       0.0  2.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    2
      1109       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    2
      1170       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    3
      1410       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    1
2     0341       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    1
      0850       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1101       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  1.0  0.0    2
      1102       0.0  0.0  0.0   4.0   6.0  12.0   6.0  1.0  0.0   13
      1105       0.0  0.0  1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
3     0301       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  1.0    1
      0342       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  1.0    1
      0343       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  1.0    1
      0501       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1101       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0  1.0  0.0    2
      1102       1.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   1.0  11.0  14.0  9.0  3.0   14
      1105       0.0  1.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1145       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    1
      1146       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  1.0  0.0    1
      1170       0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0  0.0  0.0    2
All              2.0  8.0  4.0  11.0  11.0  14.0  15.0  9.0  4.0   17
```

**Reference:**

pd.loc:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

pd.xs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html

pd.iloc:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer

Comment: When I saw the multiple index problem , I always recommend reset_index() and get what you need , then set_index back

Comment: Thanks, Wen!  I did consider resetting the index but this particular block of code is referencing the dataset from a csv import that is called from inside a dash/plotly callback function.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to do the resetting thing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on the ask, but would

`df.groupby(df.index).count()[13]` or `df.groupby(df.index).sum()[13]` for a column, or

`df.groupby(['Level','JobSeries']).sum().loc[1,341]` for a row

accomplish what you're looking for? The `level` argument in the `groupby` is designed to deal with multi-index problems

Comment: Thanks, G.Anderson.  I am just trying to get counts and sum totals for index(single and multiple) and columns (single or multiple).  I tried your groupby above and I get the following:   TypeError:  count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Comment: Unfortunately, G.Anderson - these recommendations did not work.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I just don't understand the problem as well as I need to. Is this helpful at all? `df.loc[(2),(1102),:]` from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) edit to add: The copy of your DF I'm using has num indexes, not str